# Unable to parse clientContext as json AWS Lambda

Tags: android, json, amazon-web-services, lambda

I'm getting "Unable to parse clientContext as json" error in CloudWatch when invoking my AWS Lambda function (UNHANDLED error in terms of AWS Lambda). I investigated that it's due to non-latin symbols passed internally to ClientContext class, particularly the error shows up when using non-latin symbols in Android Manifest file in android:label attribute. After debugging I saw that ClientContext codes whole object into base64 string properly and passes it to the server. But something goes wrong on the server side. The Lambda function fails with this error even before exports.handler function begins. To reproduce the bug just set android:label="@string/app_name" and set Это тест in your android manifest, then invoke any Lambda function using LambdaInvokerFactory.

The tracelog is:

```
    com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaFunctionException: 
    Unhandled at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaInvocationHandler.processInvokeResult(LambdaInvocationHandler.java:125)                                                                                      
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lambdainvoker.LambdaInvocationHandler.invoke(LambdaInvocationHandler.java:64)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
```

We workaround is:

```
Lambda function is called like this:
        try {
            o = getOrderService(context).closeOrder(this);
        } catch (LambdaFunctionException lfe) {
            Log.e("closeOrder", "Failed to execute closeOrder", lfe);
        }
```

The lambda function is declared this way:

```
 public interface IOrderService {
      @LambdaFunction
        Order closeOrder(Order order);
}
```

On AWS side Lambda function looks like this:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = function(order, context) {
    console.log('function closeOrder');
    console.log('payload');
    console.log(order);
....

}
```

Device is Android 5.0, locale ru-RU, I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1.

Comment: Where do you see this error? Any stacktrace? Would you please provide code to reproduce it?

Comment: I think it's a bug in AWS Lambda internationalization. When setting in Android app_name using non-Latin symbols (for ex. Cyrillic), constantly getting Lambda invocation error "Unable to parse clientContext as json". It seems like inside ClientContext class decoding from base64 doesn't work properly. When using latin-only symbols, everything just fine. In Android,  app_name is visible on the home screen.

To reproduce the bug just set android:label="@string/app_name" and set <string name="app_name">Это тест</string> in your manifest and you'll get the error.

Comment: I still don't get where you see this error? Do you fail to invoke lambda function on Android?

Comment: Yes. I edited the question and added more clear explanation. Please check above.  The error in returned by Lambda Invoker.

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? The latest is v2.2.13 and has a few fixes about internalization.

Comment: I used v2.2.12. And I've tried v2.2.13, but nothing changed. I added tracelog above. As you can see it goes from processInvokeResult function which is more about server side. I don't think it's SDK's fault.

Comment: The information you provided isn't enough to diagnose the issue. We need a reliable way to reproduce the issue. What's your lambda function? How is it defined? In what platform? How do you invoke the function? Does it work in the console? What is your Android device, platform version, locale info?

Comment: I added some information, please, check if it's enough. If you are from AWS team, maybe it's better to communicate some other way? email?